# How to concatenate a string to MySQL resultset

Tags: mysql

Consider the following table:

```
id  foo
-----------
1   bar
2   baz
3   bat
```

Desired output (from SQL query):

```
id str_id foo
--------------
1  str1   bar
2  str2   baz
3  str3   bat
```

In this case, "str" is concatenated to every id. Is this possible and if so how, in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `id`, CONCAT('str', `id`) AS `str_id`, `foo`
FROM `tbl`
ORDER BY `id` ASC;
```

Comment: I'll say it again( see below): LOL...so obvious I'm ashamed actually...thought it would be quite complex, using temp tables and combining them and what not. You were 7 secs faster so here's the accepted-answer karma. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to *concatenate* strings in MySQL.

```
SELECT id, CONCAT("str", id) AS str_id, foo FROM yourtable
```

Comment: LOL...so obvious I'm ashamed actually...thought it would be quite complex, using temp tables and combining them and what not

Comment: No worries. MySQL has a lot of functions. Might be worth it to browse the link I provided.